# Not able to execute PayPal Banner Script in Angular 4

Tags: angular, paypal, banner

I am trying to integrate PayPal banner in my Angular 4 application.
I have this below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-pp-payerid="XXXXXXXXXX" data-pp-placementtype="728x90" data-pp-style="BLUWHTYLRG">
    (function (d, t) {
        "use strict";
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
      n.src="//www.paypalobjects.com/upstream/bizcomponents/js/merchant.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
    }(document, "script"));
</script>
```

This code is working good if placed within `body` tag only but from any components it is not working as angular is removing `script` tag from template body. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't use `<script>` inside a component, but it's most likely for security or AoT reasons. Either way, it's a bad practice for an Angular component.

I have no real solution for you, but this is what I would try.

In your component's template add an element to hold the attribute data, and give it a `#target` reference.

```
<span #target data-pp-payerid="XXXXXXXXXX" data-pp-placementtype="728x90" data-pp-style="BLUWHTYLRG">
```

You can now access that DOM element via the `@ViewChild` attribute.

```
@ViewChild('target')
public target: ElementRef;
```

Now you just insert a `<script>` element to load the `merchant.js`.

```
public OnInit() {
    const n = document.createElement('script');
    n.src="//www.paypalobjects.com/upstream/bizcomponents/js/merchant.js";
    this.target.nativeElement.appendChild(n);
}
```

I'm not sure this will work. I don't understand how `merchant.js` can read the attributes from a parent node in the DOM. When a script loads it doesn't have a reference to the original `<script>` tag that loaded it.

**Edit:**

This answer could be updated to use the `Document` injectable, and the `Render2` service so that it supports server-side rendering.

Comment: I am facing this error `this.target.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: @ParnabSanyal try `this.target.nativeElement.appendChild` instead.